# what is twitter dialog/oauth url for authentication using twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I want url for twitter authentication.

I have facebook url for authentication like `(www.facebook.com/dialog/oatuh)`
e.g `var builder = new UriBuilder("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");`

so now i want to authentication using twitter then what i should do in `UriBuilder("?").`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter's implementation of OAuth requires a little more work than Facebook.

I would start with [Twitter's OAuth Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens) if you're determined to write your own code.  I **strongly** recommend finding a library; there are good libraries out there for almost every language what someone else has already done.

Comment: hello DWRoelands,  now i change the permission this error occurred.... You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information........and when i insert mobile number in my profile setting then this error occurred......Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet!.. please help me...

Comment: It sounds pretty straightforward - Twitter doesn't support your carrier.  Best to follow up with Twitter on this question.

Comment: I recommend @abraham library google it, works for 1.1 api too